# Is there a faster way to perform this mysql query?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, query-performance

Is there a faster way to perform this most simple query in terms of server load? I don't think I've ever tried anything other than this method:

```
$sql = 'SELECT thing FROM table WHERE id="' . $id . '" ';
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$thing = $row[0];
```

Any way to improve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance wise you can create an **index** on `id` if not already done.

Security wise you are open to SQL-injection attack, use [prepares statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.